# Javascript function for onclick

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick, peoplesoft

This link calls the javascript event onclick.  I don't know what this part is doing though:

```
"javascript:iContentOpen('/psc/'+iGetSiteName()+'/EMPL/EMP/d/EPPCM_CONTENT_MMT.EPM_PUB_VIEWER.GBL?Action=U&EPPCM_CONTENTID=9732&EPPCM_CATG_TYPE=R',true)"
```

This is part of a Peoplesoft application.  Could someone please explain to me what happens when the user clicks this link?  Here is the rest of the code..

```
<a id="Left" class="NCCPUSHBUTTON" onclick="javascript:iContentOpen('/psc/'+iGetSiteName()+'/EMPL/EMP/d/EPPCM_CONTENT_MMT.EPM_PUB_VIEWER.GBL?Action=U&EPPCM_CONTENTID=9732&EPPCM_CATG_TYPE=R',true)" href="javascript:;">
```

Comment: Naïve answer: When the user click on the link, the javascript method is fired.

Comment: `iContentOpen` is called with 2 parameters, a `string` and a `boolean`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It starts out with a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) that does nothing because there is no loop (presumably the author thinks they are saying "this is JavaScript" (they aren't)).

Then it calls a function with two arguments, a string (made up of concatenating some other strings and the return value of another function call) and a boolean.

You haven't shared those two functions with us (and they aren't JS built-ins or browser build-ins) so we have no idea what they might do.